# How do I make my mirrored object work independently?

Tags: modeling, mirror

I've made a human using the mirror modifier, but now that I'm almost done, I want to be able to edit the body on both sides without the mirror effect. I want to move around the left arm without the right one moving, and I want to be able to interarct directly with the right side (which is the mirrored side).

I've looked for a while and have found different suggestions and solutions, but non of them has worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the modifier using Apply button, that is located below the modifier name. Then you will be able to edit both sides separately. [image]

Comment: Oh god, it was that easy?! Thank you:)